# Exhibit a non-principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, maximal-and-prime-ideals

It is well-known that in a Noetherian UFD, every height one prime ideal is principal. I was wondering whether this statement holds if one replaces 'UFD' with 'locally factorial domain'. I am aware of the fact that 'locally factorial' in general does not imply 'factorial', i.e., 'unique factorization' (though have never come accross locally factorial domains that are not UFDs), so I believe that there is a counterexample to this. However I cannot come up with any.

Comment: To clarify: by locally factorial you mean that the localisation at any prime ideal is an UFD?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Any Dedekind domain is Noetherian and locally factorial, and all non-zero prime ideals have height one, but there are Dedekind domains which are not PIDs.

Comment: @user26857 I am not sure I understand correctly what you are saying, but I believe there are Dedekind domains that are not locally factorial domains. For example, it is known that every locally factorial Krull domain (whence in particular Dedekind domain) has a finitely generated class group. Yet not all Dedekind domains have finitely generated class group. For the former claim see Prop 4.1 in [Anderson and Anderson "Locally factorial integral domains"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(84)90214-X)

Comment: @quid Please read the comments above to see what means for the OP that a ring is "locally factorial", and compare with definition given by the linked paper.

Comment: @user26857 sorry for the noise, that was silly of me. // OP: I recommend you do not refer to this as locally factorial as this  has a standard meaning different from the one you use.

Answer (score 0):

A Dedekind domain is locally factorial in that for each (nonzero) prime
ideal $P$ we have $D_{P}$ a UFD. Now $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a Dedekind domain.
Check that the ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is a prime ideal.

Also, Lemma 3.1 in this paper [[CDZ]](http://www.lohar.com/researchpdf/Chang-Dumitrescu-Zafrullah(20140527).pdf) says:

An integral domain $D$ is factorial if and only if every minimal prime
of a nonzero principal ideal of $D$ is principal.

Now a Dedekind domain $D$ is an integrally closed noetherian domain of Krull
dimension $1.$ So every nonzero prime ideal of a Dedekind domain is the
minimal prime of a principal ideal, being of height one. By Lemma 3.1 of
[CDZ], if every nonzero prime ideal of a Dedekind domain $D$ is principal, 
then $D$ is a PID. So take a Dedekind domain such as $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ which know to be not a PID (i.e. not a UFD). Then you know, without an exhibition that there must be at least one nonzero prime ideal $P$ that is not principal.

[CDZ] Gyu Whan Chang, Tiberiu Dumitrescu and Muhammad Zafrullah, Locally GCD
domains and the ring $D+XD_{S}[X]$, Bull. Iranian Math. Soc. 42(2016), 263-284.